# How to link to a self-created site in pinax(0.9a2)?

Tags: python, django, navigation, pinax

I have to implemented two links in my navbar! However I want to add a project written by myself to the site! The first step is to link to the site.

How to do that?

I appreciate your answer!!!

**UPDATE**

I tried it with simply writing the path into the ref link, but I get:

**Page not found (404)**

my folder is in my template directory:

```
            <li id="tab_first">
                <a href="functionality/function.html">First Usecase</a>
            </li>
```

Whats my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='/'>This</a>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it does not really work, because I get: Page not found (404)